# Network Adapter error on airgeddon

Tags: wifi, wireless, evil-twin, airgeddon

I keep getting an error on airgeddon while using my Alfa AWUS036ACH network adapter (RTL8812AU chipset).

I can launch airgeddon successfully with all requisite tools installed, select my wlan0 network, put it into monitor mode then select the Evil Twin menu.

In the Evil Twin menu I select option 9.  Evil Twin AP attack with captive portal (monitor mode needed) but it gives me an error message of:

"The interface enabled you have already selected is not a wifi card. This attack needs a wifi card selected".

My interface is a wireless adapter (Alfa AWUS036ACH) which supports monitor mode and packet injection. Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I can say that the problems you are experiencing are problems of the driver because they are printing a very different output on iwconfig commands than the rest of the drivers for the rest of the cards.

So, all the Realtek chipsets RTL88xx like yours (RTL8812AU) are having problems using airgeddon due this different output. Anyway, there are some workarounds:

Since the airgeddon v10.0 was released, there is a new awesome feature, a plugins system. Now users can develop their own custom stuff. More info here: [airgeddon Plugins System](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/Plugins%20System). What is this useful for these kind of cards? because there is a plugin to handle that awful different behavior. You can find it [here](https://github.com/OscarAkaElvis/airgeddon_realtek_chipset_fixer)

So with the plugin, you can use safely that cards with airgeddon.

Anyway, check the list of the recommended and whitelisted cards: [airgeddon Compatible Cards](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/Cards%20and%20Chipsets)

For the next v10.01 airgeddon will have removed use of ifconfig and iwconfig commands (they are deprecated). Instead, ip and iw commands are used... so for v10.01 the plugin will be no needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful! Can you please help me understand as well, does an evil twin attack require two cards or is it possible to run with just one?

Comment: Only 1 card needed. airgeddon is going to split it into two logical cards and it works like a charm if you have one of the fully compatible cards (no an RTL88xx card). Then alternatively you can choose to select a secondary card to perform what is called "DoS pursuit mode". On that mode you can use a secondary card to perform scan in background while performing Evil Twin and if the victim hops from channel, it will rearrange DoS attack on that channel automatically. But this feature is completely optional and it is asked for the user before launching the Evil Twin. Usually, one card is enough.